# list in swiftui locking up with single record on header

Tags: list, swiftui

If I run this code below , it will goto the detail view the first time, but will not goto the detail view again.  It locks up the program with no errors.

If I add a second item in the first List (0..<2) it runs fine.  Any ideas ?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView() .navigationBarTitle("Test Detail")){
                    Text("Goto Detail").foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Welcome")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
            List(0 ..< 5) { item in
                Text("hello").foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 11.2.1 / iOS 13.2.2

Comment: does not work with version - Xcode Version 11.3

Comment: update - this will work on a device with 13.3.  however, it still will not work with xcode 11.3 simulator or xcode editor.